# Any examples of event-based jQuery programming structure?

Tags: jquery, triggers, bind, event-driven

I've built a program that I think could benefit from a shift toward using jQuery's events (bind() and trigger()) instead of the typical function-calling programming structure. For example, instead of:

```
//device changed
//(diffs holds key: {old_val: 'old value', new_val: 'new value'} pairs)
DEVICES.update(device, diffs)
DIAGRAM.update(device, diffs)
TABLES.update(DEVICES.$table, device, diffs)

/*
...
*/

//device changed - some other code location
DEVICES.update(device, diffs);
DIAGRAM.update(device, diffs);
TABLES.update(DEVICES.$table, device, diffs);
```

I could write:

```
//DEVICES.update(), DIAGRAM.update, and TABLES.update have all been bound to
//DEVICES.$container's device_changed custom event (in their respective modules)

//device changed
//(diffs holds key: {old_val: 'old value', new_val: 'new value'} pairs)
DEVICES.$container.trigger('device_changed', [device, diffs]);

/*
...
*/

//device changed - some other code location
DEVICES.$container.trigger('device_changed', [device, diffs]);
```

I'm learning how to use bind() and trigger() effectively, but mostly just making it up as I go along. Are there any good examples of how to program/structure code following this event-driven style with jQuery?

Comment: Im trying to learn i myself. Reading http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2008/12/event-pooling-with-jquery-using-bind-and-trigger-managing-complex-javascript/ - http://yoan.dosimple.ch/blog/2008/04/30/ and http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/04/custom-events-in-jquery-open-doors-to-complex-behaviors/

Comment: Sweet, these look like a great place to start! Thanks!